# Swift - How to handle audio session interruptions while recording video

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avaudiosession, notificationcenter

I'm trying to fix a behavior of my iOS application. There is a camera plug-in in the application that allows the user to record videos and take pictures. While recording a video, if an interruption occurs such as an incoming call or an alarm sound, the camera frezees and the video is not saved. I would like to handle this situation interrupting the video and saving it or removing the audio while it keeps recording.
But after the interruption starts and the event is recognized, the variables regarding the video already recorded are reinitialized, causing the app not to save anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

†

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?


public func fileOutput(\_: AVCaptureFileOutput, didStartRecordingTo \_: URL, from \_: \[AVCaptureConnection\]) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionInterruptionBegin), name: .AVCaptureSessionWasInterrupted, object: captureSession)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionInterruptionEnd),name: .AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEnded, object: captureSession)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioSessionInterrupted), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance)
print("STO PASSANDO DA AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate")

        captureSession?.beginConfiguration()
        if flashMode != .off {
            _updateIlluminationMode(flashMode)
        }
    
        captureSession?.commitConfiguration() //at this point captureSession starts collecting data about the video
    
    }

extension CameraManager {
        @objc func sessionInterruptionBegin(notification: Notification) {
                print("Capture Session Interruption begin Notification!")
                guard let reasonNumber = notification.userInfo?\        [AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey\] as? NSNumber else {
                return
}
let reason = AVCaptureSession.InterruptionReason(rawValue: reasonNumber.intValue)

        switch reason {
            case .audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient:
                removeAudioInput()
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    
    func addAudioInput() throws {
        if audioDeviceInput != nil {
            return
        }
        removeAudioInput()
    
        print("Adding audio input...")
        captureSession?.beginConfiguration()
        guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) else {
            throw NSError()
        }
        audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
        guard captureSession!.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput!) else {
            throw NSError()
        }
        captureSession?.addInput(audioDeviceInput!)
        captureSession?.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
        captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
    }
    
    func removeAudioInput() {
        //when the code reaches this point audioDeviceInput is reinitialized so the audio session is not removed from the recording
         //captureSession is not filled with the data about the video recorded
        guard let audioInput = audioDeviceInput else {
            return
        }
        captureSession?.beginConfiguration()
        captureSession?.removeInput(audioInput)
        audioDeviceInput = nil
        captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
    }
    
    @objc func sessionInterruptionEnd(notification: Notification) {
        print("Capture Session Interruption end Notification!")
        guard let reasonNumber = notification.userInfo?[AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey] as? NSNumber else {
            return
        }
        let reason = AVCaptureSession.InterruptionReason(rawValue: reasonNumber.intValue)
    
        switch reason {
            case .audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient:
                // add audio again because we removed it when we received the interruption.
                configureAudioSession()
            default:
                // don't do anything, iOS will automatically resume session
                break
        }
    }
    @objc func audioSessionInterrupted(notification: Notification) {
        print("Audio Session Interruption Notification!")
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
              let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
              let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
        }
    
        switch type {
            case .began:
                print("The Audio Session was interrupted!")
                removeAudioInput()
            case .ended:
                print("The Audio Session interruption has ended.")
                guard let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else { return }
                let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
                if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                    print("Resuming interrupted Audio Session...")
                    // restart audio session because interruption is over
                    configureAudioSession()
                } else {
                    print("Cannot resume interrupted Audio Session!")
                }
            @unknown default: ()
        }
    }
    
    func configureAudioSession() {
        let start = DispatchTime.now()
        do {
            try self.addAudioInput()
    
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            if audioSession.category != .playAndRecord {
                // allow background music playback
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .defaultToSpeaker])
            }
    
            // activate current audio session because camera is active
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            switch error.code {
                case 561_017_449:
                    print(error.description)
                default:
                    print(error.description)
            }
            self.removeAudioInput()
        }
    
        let end = DispatchTime.now()
        let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
        print("Configured Audio session in \(Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000)ms!")
    }

}
```